# What is this TFS icon and how does it differ from a folder icon?

Tags: tfs, ide, visual-studio-2013, source-control-explorer

What object does the following icon represent in TFS and how does it differ from a standard folder you might create within a team project?

[image]

I hate asking such a question but I've read around and honestly can't work it out. I've checked in the directory on my disk I have the project mapped to and it's seemingly no different to a usual folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that it is a branch and not a regular Tfs folder. Branch folders were introduced in TFS 2010 and provide some additional functionality such as support for visualization. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181425.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much mate. I'll look into how to convert to and from now that I know what it is.